# Is a manifold $R^{+}\times X$ with metric $dt^{2}+t^{2}\rm{g}_{X}$ complete?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The cone $C(X)$ over a complete manifold $X$ is defined as $R^{+}\times X$ admits the metric $dt^{2}+t^{2}g_{X}$. The manifold $C(X)$ is conformal to $Cyl(X):=\{R^{+}\times X, dt^{2}+g_{X})$. Following Hopf–Rinow theorem, it implies that $Cyl(X)$ is complete. Whether $C(X)$ is complete? Thanks very much.

Comment: If $R^+$ is $(0,\infty)$ and $t$ is a function on $X$, then the answer is no, e.g., the standard $\mathbb R^n$ with origin removed is is such a warped product with $X$ being the unit sphere and $t(x)=\|x\|$.